# Querying XML with Input Param

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Currently i am using this query to get results :

```
Select *
From Staff 
Where StaInsurance.exist('/COLInsuranceCompany/DOInsuranceCompany[Name/text()[. = "Apollo Life Assurance"]]') = 1
```

How can i use a Input Parameter instead of hardcoded string in the query, below did not work :

```
declare @IInsurance nvarchar(200)
set @IInsurance = 'Apollo Life Assurance'

Select *
From Staff 
Where StaInsurance.exist('(/COLInsuranceCompany/DOInsuranceCompany/Name[id=(sql:variable("@IInsurance"))])[1]') = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @IInsurance nvarchar(200)
set @IInsurance = 'Apollo Life Assurance'

Select *
From Staff 
Where StaInsurance.exist('/COLInsuranceCompany/DOInsuranceCompany/Name[text() = sql:variable("@IInsurance")]') = 1
```

Comment: Thanks it worked after removing the '/' from the last

Comment: @user2561997 yes, a small mistake